# Display two partial views in one view page at once

Tags: entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a web based software using Asp.net MVC 5 with EF framework on Visual Studio 2013.

I have a view page which needs to display two partial views at a given time. The partial views are associated with 2 model classes thus will be be from two Controllers. How to specify which frame the partial view should be displayed?

I'm new to MVC 5 so I am unable to provide a more detailed description. Any suggestion that can get me the result below would be helpful

[image]

Comment: For any one who face a similar problem, Method 1. Html.Action suggested by @TrueBlueAussie worked for me. I called the method through javascripts as shown in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043392/how-to-refresh-partial-view-after-table-row-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least a couple of options:

### 1 @Html.Action

Just use `@Html.Action` (twice) to render the partial views using separate controller calls:

e.g.

```
   @Html.Action("action1", "Controller", new { id = Model.idOfPart1 }

   @Html.Action("action2", "Controller", new { id = Model.idOfPart2 }
```

Where the id's are the key/lookup values you would normally pass to a control if they were full views.

`Action()` causes a full call to the action of the controller specified and renders the result in-place in the parent view.

### 2 @Html.Render

If instead you wish to pass a combined ViewModel to the parent view, and send parts of the model to each partial view, you can use `@Html.Partial`:

```
   @Html.Render("ParialView1", Model.model1);

   @Html.Render("PartialView2", Model.model2 }
```

This version passes specific models requesting each partial view render with it.

`Render()` is probably the most common model for passing data to partial views, but it really depends on how you want to pass the data around and how your controllers are structured. I always use `Action` when I think a partial view should be able to function as a view as well as a partial view.

Comment: Thank you.. I think what I need is the first solution you have suggested. I'll try that and post the results